# Python dictionary memory usage

Tags: python, memory, dictionary

I've been working on a project that involves loading a relatively large dictionary into memory from a file. The dictionary has just under 2 million entries, each entry (key and value combined) is under 20 bytes. The size of the file on disk is 38 MB.

My problem is that when I try to load the dictionary, my program immediately expands to over 2.5 gigabytes of memory used.

Here is the code I use to read the dictionary in from disk:

```
f = open('someFile.txt', 'r')
rT = eval(f.read())
f.close()
```

Comment: Have you tried [pickle](http://docs.python.org/library/pickle.html)?

Comment: what are the types of the key and value?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think the memory is used to parse the dictionary syntax AST.

For this kind of use it's much better if you go for the [cPickle](http://docs.python.org/library/pickle.html?highlight=cpickle) module instead of using `repr`/`eval`.

```
import cPickle

x = {}
for i in xrange(1000000):
    x["k%i" % i] = "v%i" % i
cPickle.dump(x, open("data", "wb"), -1)

x = cPickle.load(open("data", "rb"))
```

`-1` when dumping means using latest protocol that is more efficient but possibly not backward compatible with older python versions. If this is a good idea or not depends on why you need to dump/load.

Comment: you might also want to use the json module

Comment: Shelve is a good alternative too. It's designed for huge dictionaries which may be partially stored on disk.

Comment: Thanks! I haven't had a chance to implement this yet, but I read up on pickle a little bit; it seems like that should fix the problem.

Comment: I ended up using cPickle, which worked perfectly... Memory footprint is down to a more reasonable level, and the dictionary loads MUCH faster. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

This may be a bit off-topic, but it can also helps tremendously using generator expressions when working with big files/streams of data.

[This discussion explains it very well](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/231767/the-python-yield-keyword-explained) and [this presentation](http://www.dabeaz.com/generators/Generators.pdf) changed the way I wrote my programs.